# Is there a list of all "Inconsistencies" in WH40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Given that all WH40k lore is written by multiple authors, it is normal that once in a while there are some contradictions between works, is there a list of all these inconsistencies, has GW ever has to speak up about what it is and what's not canon?

Comment: As Yasskier states in his answer, there is not even a list of retconned lore, specially no official one. Inconsistencies are even more difficult to track.

Comment: @Shade nope, I'm not asking what it is canon perse, I mean the last part of the question is included there as it is basically if GW has ever said if something has been changed, what I want to know if there's a list of contradictions between authors, like "Author 1 wrote that this character died this way but Author 2 says he died this other way"

Answer (score 10):

Something very important about the lore in WH40k is, is that it is written as it is known to the Imperium. So, there is no all knowing author laying bare everything there is to know about all the factions, every minuscule detail is revealed in a technical manual like for [Star Trek](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345340744).

To the extend of my knowledge, there are basically two rules for authors within the WH40k universe:

1. The Emperor cannot die
2. The Emperor cannot be resurrected

Everything else is basically possible. And should there be any inconsistencies, they can be very easily explained by "Scribes in the Adeptus Administratum made a mistake". Or if somebody was at two places at the same time, it's due to the Warp. Can happen that people travel back in time during Warp travel. Or maybe, the message that was sent from one astropath was not properly interpreted by the receiver or maybe distorted while "travelling" through the warp. Who knows how all this can change and nobody has time to read it all and check for inconsistencies (and then follow up to correct them).

As Yasskier states in his [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/228678/120088) to "Is there a source for canon changes and retconcs in Warhammer 40K?", there is no list of retconned lore. Therefore, a list of inconsistencies (specially from GW) is hopeless to get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are inconsistencies, yes GW has talked about it, no there is no overarching list because one can't exist.  There is only one official retcon.

So the detailed explanation is that all GW books are considered unreliable narrations.  GW has let things slide into oblivion (The Squats, now Leagues of Votan, for instance) only to bring them back later with a "hey turns out that last thing we said about them only applied to THIS group or was misidentified as something else" and moved on.  Or for another example, take the fact that the Emperor was born in Mesopotamia around the dawn of civilization. This is part of the "Star Child" lore from Rogue Trader.  It was essentially ignored by GW for decades and most people considered it noncanon.... but then *Master of Mankind* came out in 2016 and Big E himself says he was a child in Mesopotamia around the dawn of civilization.

Games Workshop *intentionally* keeps things unclear, as a representation that the Imperium as a whole can't keep good records and everything is garbage.  Whole Space Marine Chapters are reported as destroyed in one publication but active in another.  Did they get wiped out after the other book's timeline?  Were the first author mistaken or using mistaken in-universe information and they were never destroyed at all?  Were they destroyed and secretly re-founded to preserve morale a-la the Imperial Fists?  Or did the new author just not get the memo?  The answer, by design, is "WHO KNOWS!??"

The only known retcon I can point to that is for-sure a retcon is the death of Eldrad Ulthran, the eldar farseer.  During GW's 13th Black Crusade worldwide campaign Eldrad was last seen getting his soul devoured by Slaanesh aboard a blackstone fortress from a 1st person point of view.  When the timeline "reset" to the Great Rift most of the events of the 13th Black Crusade were embellished or tweaked a bit rather than actually outright changed, but Eldrad very specifically survived and is still out doing his thing.